# Concavity: Definition similar to sub-modularity

Tags: convexity

We know that for $b \geq a$, and some $s \geq 0$, a concave function $f$ satisfies:

> $f(a+s) - f(a) \geq f(b+s) - f(b)$.

This is not a frequent definition of concavity, but can be found, e.g., [here](http://people.csail.mit.edu/stefje/mlss/cadiz_part1.pdf).

My question is, what is the name of this property? Is it easy to prove without Taylor Expansions?

Answer (score 5):

The property you are referring to simply states that the directional derivative of a 1-dimensional concave function is non-increasing. You should be able to find a proof for that inequality [here](https://sites.math.washington.edu/~burke/crs/408/lectures/L5-Convexity.pdf). The link proves it for convex functions, for concave functions simply reverse the sign of the inequality. I was unable to find a standard name for the inequality though, and yes it is easy to prove.